# Why browser fetches google.com with http/1.1 on the first access

Tags: http, https

- Open Chrome browser (fresh)
- Start incognito mode
- fetch google.com

It always uses http/1.1 although h3 is supported and each request that will follow will use h3.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP version negotiation is required before using HTTP/3**

HTTP/3 generally doesn’t work for the first request because browsers assume by default that the server doesn’t support HTTP/3 and send the first request via either HTTP/2 or HTTP/1.1 on a TCP connection.

If the server supports HTTP/3, it responds with an Alt-Svc (Alternative Service) header that informs the client that it can send HTTP/3 requests. The browser can respond in different ways: it can open a QUIC connection right away or wait until the TCP connection is closed.

Either way, an HTTP/3 connection is only set up after the initial resources have been downloaded over an HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 connection.

Source:
https://www.debugbear.com/blog/http3-quic-protocol-guide